# Bootstrap carousel angular multiple images

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a `Bootstrap carousel` with multiple images that includes an API rest with Angular resource.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7TNi.png)

But when I bring the API it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPCMj.png)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ruta_hbo_max" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="1000" id="hbo_mas">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item " ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="data in datos">
            <div class="col-md-3"><a><img src="{{ data.ruta }}{{ data.nombre }}.jpg"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) 
      {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i=0;i<2;i++) 
      {
          next=next.next();
          if (!next.length) 
          {
              next = $(this).siblings(':first');
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
   });
});
```

I've run out of ideas to solve I hope someone can help me thanks

Comment: You can use a library for that, there's one exclusive with bootstrap components [Angular ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)

Comment: but to consume the rest api?

Comment: to consume them, you just load in an array and pass that parameter to angular, so when it load the carousel, load the array with images

Answer (score 0):

Hi I could solve leaving my jquery script follows . but now my problem is that it works in firefox and explorer. but chrome still shows me one by one that could be ? Thank you for your attention.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.item').each(function(){
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length)
            {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            for (var i=0;i<2;i++) 
            {
                next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) 
            {
              next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```